# Mesh Cleanup - Self Intersection and Dual Face Removal

Tags: mesh

I am super new to Blender and been working on a simple mesh (for 3D-printing if that matters). Long story short I screwed up big time and now have a mesh which has a lot of co-planar intersecting faces (see image). My question is how do I make Blender join up the co-planer faces and create vertices where edges intersect planes so I can remove interior faces? And if this isn't possible how do I do it myself in the best (read proper) way? Obviously I should try to avoid creating this problem in the first place so any general guidelines for that would be great as well. Maybe it just requires practise and a little bit of thought ahead of time, what do I know.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the Blender file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please consider sharing your blendfile https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can have a look.
Without that, it’s just guessing.

Comment: Yes of course, it's added now.

Comment: Good news. Your mesh is pretty simple, so I’d reccomend to rebuild it from scratch.
It’ll give you a cleaner mesh, and it will be less work in the end. 
I could post an answer with some useful tips, if you’re interested.

Comment: Yes please. I made this mesh myself so if I do it again it will most likely end up with the same issues as last time if I don't get any pointers as to where I went wrong

Comment: Sure thing. Answer is coming up, but it’ll take a minute :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is pretty simple, I would recommend to repair it manually.

Here’s how I’d do it.
The repaired Blendfile is attached at the end.

1) Set units to milimetres and snapping to Increments.
Enable absolute grid snap. This will make it waaay easier to achieve accurate results.
It’s very useful for precise modeling (like for 3D printing)

[image]

[image]

2) Remove half of your mesh. Because it’s symmetrical, we’ll work only on one half, and generate the other one automatically.
- Also remove all the overlapping end faces
- The middle part was kinda messed up, so I repaired it manually. It was easy, try it for yourself.

I’ve put the repaired mesh into the blender file for you. Use it to follow the next steps.
You’re welcome :).

[image]

3) Add two loopcuts. Don’t worry about an exact position, you can adjust it later.

[image]

4) Select faces you don’t need and delete them. *Press Delete->Faces*

[image]

5) Select the four vertices on top and *Press F* to *fill*.
Do the same thing for the bottom four vetices.

[image]
[image]

6) Select the front loop by clicking *Alt+LMB* on a vertex and *Press F* to *fill*.
Do the same for the back loop.

[image] [image]
[image]

7) You’re almost done.
Now you have a perfect half of your handle.

Now select the mesh and *Click RMB->Set Origin to 3Dcursor*. This is gonna be important in the next step.

[image]

7.1) Correct normals
*Click Overlay->Face orientation* to show the normals.
Red faces should be inside, blue on the outside.

Select all faces with *Select->All* and go to *Mesh->Normals->Recalculate Outside.* Blender will then recalculate them correctly.

*You can see some inverted normals in your original mesh.*
[image]

8) Add a mirror modifier.
Set the correct axis (Y in this example).

[image] [image]

9) You can select the loop (use *X-ray mode*), and move it up or down as you like.
The other half of your mesh will adjust itself.

[image]

10) Done.
You’ve got a clean mesh without any non-planar or overlapping faces.

Repaired Blender file
- Includes the end result
- Includes the Step 01 mesh.
[image]

Aaaaaah.
God damn, that took longer than I expected.

Additional tips:
- Apply all modifiers before exporting file for 3D printer
- Check BlenderGuru for basic Blender tutorials
- You’re doing great, happy Blendering

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear and consice answer! I would give you an upvote if I had enough reputation . I will follow along in your steps when I get home but can I ask exactly how you removed the overlapping faces in step 2? I tried to do this but all faces seemed to have several faces embedded in them. It was all very confusing and time consuming. Not sure if it even gave any results. I also tried to "Merge by distance" (it seems like that should remove overlapping faces) but it didn't do it for me.

Comment: I just used *Delete-Faces*, one after another, until no face remained :). Merge by distance didn’t work at all.
There were also some forgotten edge loops, that I dissolved with *Delete->Dissolve Edges* but luckily, the main parts of your mesh were okay.

Comment: Okay cool, I'll see if I can repeat your steps all the way from the beginning of my screwed up mesh . Thanks again!

Comment: Great. If you’ll need any clarification, let me know. Happy blendering :).

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I followed your instructions from my own rubbish mesh (after cleaning it myself) and it looks great! I think it is perfectly clean now. Thank you, you were invaluable.

Comment: @IvarEriksson  Thanks for feedback man, you just made my day :).